# tar a folder into multiple files over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

Here is the thing

I have a server with total 85 GB disk space and right now i have a folder with the size of 50 GB which is containing over 60000 files .

Now i want to download these files on my localhost and in order to do that i need to tar the folder but I can't tar the whole folder because of disk space limitation.

So i'm looking for a way to archive the folder into two 25 GB tar file like part1.tar and part2.tar but when the first part is done it should wait for asking something like next part name or permission or anything so I can transfer the first part to an another server and then continue archiving to part2. Or a way to tar half of the folder like first 30000 files and then tar the rest.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try rsync.  I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync solution was good enough but i found the solution for main question:

```
tar -c -M --tape-length=30000000 --file=filename.tar foldername
```

After reaching 29GB you will need to change the tape(in my case transferring the first part and removing it) and hit enter for continue.Additionally it is possible for give next parts name:

```
Prepare volume #2 for `filename.tar' and hit return:

n filename2.tar
```

Because it is going to take time i suggest using screen session over SSH :
http://thelinuxnoob.com/linux/screen-in-ssh/

Answer (score 2):

One of the earliest applications of rsync was to implement mirroring or backup for multiple Unix clients to a central Unix server using rsync/ssh and standard Unix accounts.

I use rsync to move compressed (and uncompressed) files between servers.

I think the command should be something like this

```
rsync -av host::src /dest
```

Comment: I use rsync for transfering between two servers too but is there anyway to filter files in rsync? like just transfer some files like first 30000 of them? as i said i have disk space limitation on both servers.Another option would be scp but i need that way to just select some files and in next step select the rest .there is no difference if i'm using tar or sending them with rsync or scp or anyway

Comment: According to the man page `-f, --filter=RULE           add a file-filtering RULE`

Comment: There is also this option. ` -F                          same as --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'
                             repeated: --filter='- .rsync-filter'
     --exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
     --exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
     --include=PATTERN       don't exclude files matching PATTERN
     --include-from=FILE     read include patterns from FILE
     --files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE`